# How to run scripts automatically after doing vagrant ssh?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am new to Vagrant but good in Docker.

In Vagrant I am aware of the fact that 
`config.vm.provision :shell,path: "bootstrap.sh", run: 'always'` 
in the Vagrantfile will provision vagrant box while doing `vagrant up`. With this, the vagrant box interactive console appears after the intended provisioning is done.

But I need to configure in such a way that, first the control goes in to vagrant box console and then the intended script is up and running. Because my requirement is to run a script automatically post `vagrant up` and not to run a bootstrapped script.

In analogy with Docker, my question can be seen as

> what is the Vagrant equivalent for CMD in Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [vagrant triggers](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers/usage). You can run dedicated script/command after each specific vagrant command (`up`, `destroy` ...)

For example

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Your existing Vagrant configuration
  ...
  
  # start apache on the guest after the guest starts
  config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
    trigger.run_remote = {inline: "service apache2 start"}
  end

end
```

Comment: No longer works? `Message: undefined method \`run_remote'`

Comment: @ViliusL updating as triggers are now part of vagrant core and do not need a plugin